# Need a .net regex to block all spaces and the @ character

Tags: regex

I have the .net expression to block spaces but no idea how to modify it to also block the `@` character.

Current expression to block spaces: `^\s*\S+\s*$`

Comment: `^\s*\S+\s*$` actually allows leading and trailing spaces. A hint: `\S` = `[^\s]` (a *negated* character class). You may add more characters/shorthand character classes into a negated character class that you do not want to match.

Comment: Don't know what you mean by 'block'. The regex you provide will grab things that have surrounding spaces, so not only `text` but also `^   text   $` (where `^` and `$` aren't actually present, just showing the anchors to help formatting work properly) - is that what you want? Provide some sample input texts, and outputs ("want to match" vs "don't match", perhaps") and we can better help

Comment: Are you using that inside .NET code? Or is it for some tool (Nintex?) You know, you could just use 2 methods: `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` and `String.Contains`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `^` inside `[ ]` to block what you don't want to be matched :

```
^[^\s@]+$
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/vW8aT3/2)